# How to update user-defined field in gerrit using gerrit-review command line?

Tags: git, rest, gerrit

we have a field "topic" in the gerrit, its editable from GUI, is there a way to update it using gerrit-review command line? looking for some command like below:

```
ssh -p $port $server gerrit review --topic="some topic" $gerrit_change_num
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that using the "gerrit review" command, but you can do it using the REST API like in the following example:

```
curl --request PUT --user USER:PASS --data @- --header Content-Type:application/json https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/CHANGE-NUMBER/topic <<EOF
{
    "topic": "TOPIC-NAME"
}
EOF
```

See more info [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#set-topic)